# Vue.js Vue3 different Templating with for sub components

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I have a Vue 3 project,

Most of my Components use the Template in App.vue (My understanding goes that this is Similar to a "Master Page in .net core with the completeness inheriting the style and layout from the App.vue. In my case, the app.vue will have the dashboard layout (top and sides) and then I will load the restricted components in the content section.

However, I cannot seem to figure out how to make public-facing pages, such as login and register not reference the Dashboard template at all as they are not logged in, but still allow some Vue functionality. Post for login, errors returned, etc. How can I split them or have multiple Master App.vue templates for different users, based on their role or logged-in status.

your help is greatly appricated.

Comment: You could make different layouts and render the right layout based on the current route as I did here https://github.com/boussadjra/vue3-tailwind2/blob/main/src/App.vue

Comment: thanks, i seems like the idea, just a small question in the computed method, am I able to say if Logged (have a method to check if a user is logged in) in return "logged in layout" else return default layout.

Comment: Yes you could add that condition like `return this.userIsLoggedIn?'auth-layout':'default-layout'`

Answer (score 0):

In App.vue you can use vue js built in component tag to render dynamic layouts

```
<component :is="activeLayout"></component>
```

you can bind it to a computed property and return the appropriate component to bind for different scenarios